# grep: piping into grep -r doesn't work correct

Tags: grep, pipe, tcsh

My grep command is aliased to 'grep -r' , in new grep version it causes me the following problem:
when piping one grep to another, the second grep does not search what I want from the outcome of the first one, as it should, but it search the entire folder like a new grep. for example:

```
grep -r "something" folder | grep -r "something2"
```

the second grep performs a search at the entire folder instead of searching only the output of the first grep. that happens because of the -r flag, without it everything is fine.
Assuming I don't want to delete this -r flag from my grep alias, is there any solution?

Comment: you could use `\grep` for the second one, it will override the alias

Comment: another suggestion would be to use `ripgrep` which performs recursive search by default and handles stdin as well

Comment: TNX! ripgrep works great! I can alias my grep to ripgrep. but does ripgrep has the same attributes as grep? same flags and all?

Comment: please don't alias ripgrep to grep, use the default `rg` name and keep `grep` separate... and no, `rg` doesn't have same features and some flags are different..  I have a [tutorial](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnugrep_ripgrep/ripgrep.html) if you wish to go through the basics

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but the second `grep -r` makes no sense:

`grep -r` means grep recursively, so do not only look at the current folder, but also to sub-, subsub- and deeper folders.

For the first `grep -r`, I can relate to that: look for "something" in the folder and in all subfolders, but the second: once you have found "something" inside one particular file, I want you to verify all sub-, subsub- and deeper folders for "something2".

How can you go deeper inside a directory structure while you are checking inside a single file?

I would advise you not to add the `-r` switch in your `grep` alias.

Comment: but then I'll have to add -r every time I do want to search something recursively. which is in use more times...

Comment: @maorshariki: what are you trying to do? You are looking for a piece of text in a file, which is located somewhere inside some directory structure. Once you have found an occurence of that piece of text inside a particular file, located in some directory, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to perform a search in that piece of text to find something in it **without removing -r flag from my grep alias** because then I'll have to add it every time I want to search a directory

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think it's a good idea to use `grep -r` as a standard alias for `grep`: I've been working on UNIX platforms for several years and instead of `grep -r`, I've always used following system: `find <dir> -exec grep "something" {} /dev/null \;`. I admit, it's quite some writing, but it's extremely flexible and it has served all purposes.

Comment: Never mind, I have a solution. Like suggested above I am using ripgrep... tnx anyway!

Comment: Why don't you create an alias like `alias dgrep='grep -r'` (which stands for "directory grep"), this is easy to remember.

Comment: I created an alias grep 'rg \!*' and for now it's the same. that way I don't need seperate aliases.